# Disabled Button background disappears

Tags: c#, wpf, button, background, windows-phone

I'm really surprised about it but it appears that disabling a button on Windows Phones leads its background to disappear.

I've read some XAML solutions, however, my buttons are created programatically (I won't change that) and I have no idea about how to deal with that. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

```
table[i, j] = new Button();
table[i, j].Content = "";
table[i, j].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
table[i, j].Height = 70;
table[i, j].Width = 70;
table[i, j].Background = brush1;
Thickness m = table[i, j].Margin;
m.Left = -18;
m.Top = -20;
table[i, j].Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
table[i, j].Margin = m;
table[i, j].Tap += CoolMethod;
//The button is Added to a Grid
//Visible
//.......

//CoolMethod(){
table[i, j].IsEnabled = false;
//No longer visible
table[i, j].Background = brush2;
//Still not visible
```

The background resource is for now an ImageBrush like this :

```
ImageBrush buttonUnavailableImage = new ImageBrush();
BitmapImage imageDisabled = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/caseinactiv.png", UriKind.Relative));
buttonUnavailableImage.ImageSource = imageDisabled;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for creating the buttons as well?

Comment: In WPF setting the background brush has no effect when the button is disabled; I don't know if the same control template is used for Windows Phone.  If so, you'll need to create your buttons off a different control template.

Comment: For now, the background is an ImageBrush and disappears anyway...

Comment: What are those XAML solutions you mentioned? Chances are that you can "convert" such a solution into program code, since (afaik) everything in XAML can also be dynamically built in program code.

Comment: This solution wasn't re a background image but I think that this can be built for an image and set as style in code-behind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601371/why-does-disabling-a-button-remove-its-background-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you’re observing is caused by the button’s default control template.

To view the default style for WP7.1, open the file
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Design\System.Windows.xaml" file and search for `<Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase" TargetType="ButtonBase">`.

```
<Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase" TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <!-- skipped.. -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"><!-- skipped.. --></VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" >
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You see what happens under `<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">` element? The background of the border is replaced by the `Transparent` brush.

To modify that style, copy and paste that style into your app.xaml, and edit the `Disabled` visual state of the button's control template however you want.

Specify no `x:Key` attribute to apply that style to all buttons in your application. Alternatively, you can specify some key, and in your button creation code add the following line to apply that style manually:
`theButton.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources[ "styleKey" ];`

Comment: This looks like being exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much ! I will test that ASAP before accepting your answer